# MySQL: Transform "LIKE" search to fulltext?

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search, transform, sql-like

I have a pretty simple LIKE search for MySQL that i'd like to transform into a fulltext. The problem is i need to be able to implement it so that it starts with X. Like the example below:

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column LIKE "startswith%"
```

as you can see that query returns all results that begins with "startswith". I need to do this with a fulltext.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Do you mean `LIKE "a very long text%"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that isn't how fulltext works (it's actually just a list with loose words underneath, no information about location relative to the string) but there's no reason why you can't have that `LIKE ...` as an extra `WHERE` clause. FULLTEXT can still help to get a smaller subset of results if you haven't got another key on `column`. If you *do* have a key on `column`, using FULLTEXT for this is useless.

You can set a key on just the start of a column with `ADD INDEX (column(123));` (which would only index the first 123 characters). THis also works for text/blob columns (in the latter case it's the binary length you give).

Comment: Could you give me an example, or a link to an example? This might be what i'm looking for!

Comment: An example of what exactly? Your `LIKE` works, if you haven't got a key and don't want to use FULLTEXT but instead set my proposed key, use `ALTER TABLE tablename ADD INDEX (columname(123));` or whatever the width needs to be, if you do want to use the FULLTEXT to just get it faster, use `SELECT column FROM table WHERE MATCH(columnname) AGAINST ('your search string*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND columnname LIKE 'your search string%';`

Comment: Yeah, i'm doing it for the speed. The example you gave me works great! :)

Comment: The `INDEX` option is probably faster :P

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about MySQL, but in SQL Server you can convert the column into a `varchar` and perform a `LIKE` on the result, such as below:

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE CONVERT(varchar(255), column) LIKE 'startswidth%'
```

Since this is ANSI standard, I presume MySQL will handle this as well.

Comment: Yes, MySQL will handle it, but there's no need: the LIKE will work without the conversion.